# One word for "more you try, worse it gets"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word for  "more you try to improve, worst it gets"? Here is an example sentence - "*Being on a diet may help reduce weight but it overall worsens your health*".

Comment: Are you looking for a word that will exactly fit the meaning in the example sentence?

Comment: Thanks @KillingTime. I am looking for a word that can match many similar cases. Here is another example sentence - "Doing more mundane work may make feel like productive, but it actually slows us down due to lack of meaningful results."

Comment: You mean "worse it gets". "worst" is the superlative, and you need the comparative here.

Comment: I'm going to go out on a limb and say there is no single word for this.

Comment: It's being *counterproductive*. But happily, not everything gets worse with trying.

Comment: Thank you @PrimeMover. I have updated the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The activity is **self-defeating**. [Oxford English Dictionary](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/57123346):

> Of an action or activity: preventing attainment of the end it is designed to bring about; futile or counterproductive.

So even though the diet is intended to bring about weight reduction, certain diets may cause weight gain or other health problems, thereby preventing attainment of the original goal of the activity.

Example:

> While at first the diet helped me lose weight, the diet ended up being **self-defeating**; I gained back more than I lost.

Answer (score 0):

How about **counterproductive**, as first suggested by @Lawrence (but which occurred to me also)? From Lexico:

> **[counterproductive](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/counterproductive)**: Having the opposite of the desired effect.

Your example:

> "Being on a diet may help reduce weight but it overall worsens your health. In short, dieting is **counterproductive**.".